# Does Entity Framework call property setters with null when rehydrating entities for columns with DB NULL?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6.4

I have a string property

```
public string XYZ 
{ 
     get => // do stuff
     set => // do stuff which handles null
}
```

because I'm hoping it will get called....

But will it really?
(EF6.4)

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft so turns out I was asking about the wrong version! (Now I seem to remember someone upgraded it a couple years ago.) I'll fix the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears it will.  If you implement the property with a backing field it's easy to test this by putting a breakpoint in the setter.  EG

```
private string xyz;
public string XYZ
{
    get
    {
        return xyz;
    }
    set
    {
        xyz = value;
    }
}
```

And I think it would have to, as EF does not know whether your entities have a non-standard default value for a property.  eg you could write

```
private string xyz = "none";
public string XYZ
{
    get
    {
        return xyz;
    }
    set
    {
        xyz = value;
    }
}
```

And so the hydration code would need to run the setter to get a correct result.